# QML ColumnLayout does not respect minimumHeight

Tags: qt, layout, qml

I always have problems with the layout management of QML. So, I created a very simple QML App to check ColumnLayout. If I shrink the window horizontally, it will stop at the minimumWitdh when 100 is reached.
But if I shrink the window vertically I can shrink the window, so that both rectangles disappear.

What is going wrong? Why is the minimumHeight not respected?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout {
        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            Layout.minimumWidth: 100
            Layout.minimumHeight: 100
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "blue"
            Layout.minimumWidth: 100
            Layout.minimumHeight: 100
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the code you've provided probably is not complete and doesn't descripe the issue. The size of layout isn't set so there is no way that it can affect size of the rectangles. it always will be 100x100.

Comment: I ran the same code unter Linux Mint with Qt Online-Installer. So same version which I use on Windows. In Linux Layout.minimumWidth AND Layout.minimumHeight are ignored.

Comment: @folbis: I created this program with the standard template of an empty QtQuick Application and just added the section ColumnLayout in main.qml. So, the main.cpp is unchanged. (and I didn't want to upload it). 
I do not understand that the "size of the layout is not set". I thought the Layout.minimumWitdh and Layout.minimumHeight are attached to the recatangle, coming from ColumnLayout. And I thought the minimum sizes are propagated upwards, so that the result will be, that the minimum size of the window will be 100 in width and 200 in height in total.

Comment: The layout's size is defined by the content in your case so it will be always 100x200. The window size doesn't depend by the content unless you don't use `QQuickView::ResizeMode` set to `QQuickView::SizeViewToRootObject` and your layout is root object.

Answer (score 0):

folbis is probably right. But I found another solution. It seems the minimumWidth and minimumHeight will calculate an implicitWidth and implicitHeight of the ColumnLayout. So, this in turn can be used as minimumWidth and minimumHeight of the window, like so:

```
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    minimumHeight: col.implicitHeight
    minimumWidth: col.implicitWidth


    ColumnLayout {
        id: col

        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            Layout.minimumWidth: 100
            Layout.minimumHeight: 100
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "blue"
            Layout.minimumWidth: 100
            Layout.minimumHeight: 100
        }
    }
}
```

This is very weird, when you come from the XAML-world.